# Only display 3 tasks to a user at a time, then display 3 more once they have completed 3 tasks

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have 2 tables in my database.

First table is called tasks, which holds the task ID and the task. The second table is called completedTasks, which will hold the taskID and the username.
Once the user hits the 'Complete Task' button, it will post the taskID and their username to the completedTasks table.

I am wanting to display 3 tasks to a user at a time, and once they have completed all 3 tasks, another 3 will appear. Currently, I am able to pull out 3 tasks from the database, but once the user clicks the 'Complete Task' button, it will pull out another task from the tasks table, to make it up to 3 again, instead of only displaying the further two that they need to complete.
Any suggestions on how I can display 3 tasks, then 2, then 1, then pull out another 3 would be great!
The code that I currently have is:

```
<?php
require ("dbConnect.php");
$user_check = $_SESSION['currentUser'];

$dbQuery = $db->prepare("select taskID, task from tasks WHERE taskID NOT IN (SELECT taskID from completedTasks WHERE username = '$user_check' ) LIMIT 3");
$dbQuery-> execute();

while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $taskID=$dbRow["taskID"];
    $task=$dbRow["task"];

    echo "<div align='center'>";
    echo "<form action='mytasks.php' method='post'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='username' name='username' value='$user_check'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='taskID' name='taskID' value='$taskID'>";
        echo "<table width='40%'>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' id='task' name='task' disabled='true' value='$task'></td>
                    <td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Complete Task'></td>
                </tr>
              </table>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</div>";
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $taskID = $_POST['taskID'];

    $dbQuery=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `completedTasks` VALUES (:username, :taskID)"); 
    $dbParams = array('username'=>$username, 'taskID'=>$taskID);
    $dbQuery->execute($dbParams);
    if($dbQuery) {
        header('Location:mytasks.php');
        echo "<script>Success();</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script>Unsuccessful();</script>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$statement = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) from completedTasks WHERE username='$user_check' ");
$result = $statement->fetch();
$count = $result[0];
$count = $count-($count % 3);
$dbQuery2 = $db->prepare("SELECT taskID, task from tasks LIMIT 3 OFFSET $count");
$dbQuery2-> execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is :

1) count the number of completed tasks :
select COUNT(*) count from completedTasks WHERE username = '$user_check'

2) adjust the number to be the multiple of 3 just <= it (for example : 0 => 0, 1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3 => 3, 4 => 3...) :
$count = $count - ($count % 3)

3) skip the first $count tasks by using offset :
select taskID, task from tasks LIMIT 3 OFFSET $count

Note that for this method to work, you should always ensure that the task are in the same order, because it doesn't check whether a task has been completed or not when retrieving it

PS : note that you should be careful for sql injections by putting $user_check in raw in your query

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean on this line: 2) adjust the number to be the multiple of 3 just <= it (for example : 0 => 0, 1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3 => 3, 4 => 3...) :

Comment: Let's say you have tasks A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H in that order. If you haven't completed any, then you will show A, B, C (which means you don't do any offset, you just take the first 3 one (= OFFSET 0)). If you have completed 1, you still want to show A, B, C (still OFFSET 0). Same if you have completed 2, still OFFSET 0. However, when you have completed the first 3 tasks (A, B and C), you want to skip those 3 and show D E F, and therefore you should put OFFSET 3. When you also have completed D (thus the first 4 tasks), you still want to show D E F and the OFFSET should remain 3.

Comment: If you continue, you will see that at anytime, the number of tasks you will want to skip is the multiple of 3 just lower or equal to the total number of completed tasks

Comment: Thank you for this. It worked apart from a small part that I had to add in to be able to retrieve the count number. For your reference, my code now looks like this:
$statement = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) from completedTasks WHERE username='$user_check' ");
$result = $statement->fetch();
$count = $result[0]
$count = $count-($count % 3);
$dbQuery2 = $db->prepare("SELECT taskID, task from tasks LIMIT 3 OFFSET $count");
$dbQuery2-> execute();